# Show matplotlib figure statelessly

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's how to create a "stateful" plot in matplotlib and show it in non-interactive mode:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,8])
plt.show()
```

I am more interested in the "stateless" approach as I wish to embed `matplotlib` in my own `python` library. The same plot can be constructed "statelessly" as follows:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
lines = ax.plot([1,2,8])
```

However I don't know how to show it without resorting to `pyplot` , which I don't want to do as I would like to build up my own display mechanism.

How do I show the figure without resorting to `pyplot`?

Comment: If you want to build your own display mechanism, that would exactly the part you need to implement. For that you will want to decide where and how you want to show the figure, if you want to use existing backends, or write a new one etc. Seems all very vague from the question...

Comment: I would like to use `Qt5Agg` backend.I basically want to show the figure again every time I call a custom `.show()` command. My custom command will not behave like the `pyplot.show` command as it will only show the figure belonging to the current class... Does that help clarify things?

Comment: I suppose the [embedding_in_qt example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) is then what you're looking for.

Comment: Seems super complicated! Do I really have to go down this route?

Comment: Well, it's not that complicated, and for easier workflows there is `pyplot`.